# How to get specific parameter's value from the querystring in jquery/javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, parameters, get, query-string

I've following query string:

```
url = "http://56.177.59.250/static/ajax.php?core[ajax]=true&core[call]=prj_name.contactform&width=400&core[security_token]=c7854c13380a26ff009a5cd9e6699840"
```

I want to get the value of variable `core[call]` i.e. `prj_name.contactform`

How should I get this value using jQuery/javascript?

Please help me.

Comment: @adeneo:I asked the question here because I want value of a variable from query string which is itself in array format. I don't know how to get such kind of variable from query string. That's why I'm asking for help. So I'm kindly requesting you to please remove the "Duplicate" mark.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, which puts all variables into the `vars{}` object.  You can then access `vars.core.ajax`, `vars.width`, etc.  Also live on this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anthonyserious/beaLqhLg/):

```
var u = "http://localhost:8080/static/ajax.php?core[ajax]=true&core[call]=prj_name.contactform&width=400&core[security_token]=c7854c13380a26ff009a5cd9e6699840&x=1"
var re = /(\w+)\[(\w+)\]$/
var vars = {}
u.split('?')[1].split('&').forEach(function(e) {
    var p = e.split('=');
    var v = p[0].match(re);

    if (v === null) {
        vars[p[0]] = p[1];
    } else {
        if (!(v[1] in vars)) { vars[v[1]] = {}; }
        vars[v[1]][v[2]] = p[1];
    }
});
console.log(vars);
```